# Run-time error with stack program

Tags: java, stack

I am attempting to write a program that will utilize stacks to check if a 
left parenthesis/bracket has its coinciding right bracket/parenthesis in the user's input. Although I've vigorously searched through the code, I can't seem to find what I did wrong. The following code block is the method "checking" that I'm trying to implement.

```
import java.util.Stack;
public class Matching {

public static int checking(String s) {

    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("{") || s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("}")){ //if substring is a bracket

            if (s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("{"))  //if is left bracket push onto stack
                stack.push("{");

            else if (!stack.peek().equals("{") || stack.size() <= 0) //otherwise, check if left bracket is not at top or if stack is empty
                return 3; // "right brace does not have its matching left brace"

            else if (s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("}") && stack.peek().equals("{"))//otherwise if substring is a right brace and the top is a left brace
                stack.pop(); //remove from top, continue searching
        }

        if (s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("{") || s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("}")){ //if substring is a parenthesis

            if (s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("(")) // if is left parenthesis push onto stack
                stack.push("(");

            else if (!stack.peek().equals("(") || stack.size() <= 0) //otherwise, check if left parenthesis is not at top or if stack is empty
                return 1;

            else if (s.substring(i).equals(")") && stack.peek().equals("(")) //otherwise if substring is a right parenthesis and the top is a left parenthesis
                stack.pop(); //remove from top, continue searching
        }

        if (stack.size() == 0) //
            return 0;
        else if (stack.size() != 0 && stack.peek().equals("("))
            return 2;
        else if (stack.size() != 0 && stack.peek().equals("{"))
            return 4;
    }
    return 150; //checks for error
  }
 }
```

My problem is that the program outputs that everything is matching (returning 0) no matter the circumstances. Here is my main method as well:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Assignment11
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        char input1;
        String inputInfo;
        String line = new String();

    printMenu();

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(isr);

    do  // will ask for user input
    {
        System.out.println("What action would you like to perform?");
        line = stdin.readLine();
        input1 = line.charAt(0);
        input1 = Character.toUpperCase(input1);

        if (line.length() == 1)
        {
            // matches one of the case statements
            switch (input1)
            {
                case 'P':   //Enter String
                    System.out.print("Please enter a string.\n");
                    inputInfo = stdin.readLine().trim();
                    int result = Matching.checking(inputInfo);
                    if (result == 0)
                        System.out.println("Everything is matching");
                    else if (result == 1)
                        System.out.println("right parenthesis does not have its matching left parenthesis");
                    else if (result == 2)
                        System.out.println("left parenthesis does not have its matching right parenthesis");
                    else if (result == 3)
                        System.out.println("right brace does not have its matching left brace");
                    else if (result == 4)
                        System.out.println("left brace does not have its matching right brace");
                    break;
                case 'Q':   //Quit
                    break;
                case '?':   //Display Menu
                    printMenu();
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.print("Unknown action\n");
                    break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.print("Unknown action\n");
        }
    } while (input1 != 'Q' || line.length() != 1);
}


/** The method printMenu displays the menu to a user**/
public static void printMenu()
{
    System.out.print("Choice\t\tAction\n" +
            "------\t\t------\n" +
            "P\t\tEnter String\n" +
            "Q\t\tQuit\n" +
            "?\t\tDisplay Help\n\n");
}
```

}

Any help or general pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw The program is supposed to identify if a parenthesis/bracket does not have a closing bracket/parenthesis. However, if the user inputs something like "())" The program outputs that everything matches despite the fact that there is not a left parenthesis for every right parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at your second `if` statement:

```
if (s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("{") || s.substring(i, i + 1).equals("}")){ //if substring is a parenthesis
```

The *comment* says it's checking for left and right parens, but the *code* says...

Comment: Ah, ffs. Thank you for catching that!